# | Powershell | For Each Loop a CSV, full of names, into a XML file

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

So I'm quite a novice when it comes to powershell, I'm trying to make a script that loops through a CSV file and outputs a XML file that follows a schema. More specifically, I'm trying to take each name and output it into a single file, and have it be specifically be placed in a username spot. Eventually if I can figure this out, I can do the same to the other spots. So I guess the questions is, how does one go about doing this or setting this up?

Example XML Schema:

```
<User>  
        <Username>mike</Username>       
        <Password>iamcool</Password>
        <Email>mike@mike.com</Email>        
        <Name>Mike Jones</Name>
        <CreationDate>1125442154664</CreationDate>
        <ModifiedDate>1125442154664</ModifiedDate> 
</User>
```

Comment: Do you have a question and maybe some code you need help with?

Comment: Yes, i apologize. Im just wondering how could one like me go about setting up a script like this, and/or where I could learn more from?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use a specific xml schema, you can import a csv, and export to xml all in one go using `ConvertTo-Xml`:

```
Username, Password, Email
mike,     iamcool,  mike@mike.com
john,     hunter2,  john@john.com
```

```
# First, we import from a csv, then we can directly export to xml:
$csv = Import-CSV -Path 'c:\path\to\file.csv'
ConvertTo-XML $csv -as String -NoTypeInformation

# Or as one line, exporting to file:
Import-CSV $path | ConvertTo-Xml -as String -NoTypeInformation | Out-File $xmlpath
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Objects>
  <Object>
    <Property>
      <Property Name="Username">mike</Property>
      <Property Name="Password">iamcool</Property>
      <Property Name="Email">mike@mike.com</Property>
    </Property>
    <Property>
      <Property Name="Username">john</Property>
      <Property Name="Password">hunter2</Property>
      <Property Name="Email">john@john.com</Property>
    </Property>
  </Object>
</Objects>
```

---

If you **do** need to match an existing schema, I would do it the .Net way. For example, to try and match your sample schema:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'c:\path\to\file.csv'

# Create an XML object, and give it a declaration line
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
$dec = ($xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", $null))
$root = $xml.DocumentElement
$xml.InsertBefore($dec,$root)

# create main <body> node 
$xmlbody = $xml.CreateElement('Body')
$xml.AppendChild($xmlbody)

# import csv to custom nodes
foreach ($user in $csv) {
  # create <user> container node
  $xmluser = $xml.CreateElement('User')
  $xmlbody.AppendChild($xmluser)

  # add each property from csv entry to <user>
  Foreach ($property in $csv[0].psobject.Properties.name) {
    # create a property node
    $xmlproperty = $xml.CreateElement($property)
    $text = $xml.CreateTextNode($user.$property)
    $xmlproperty.AppendChild($text)

    # add to current <User> node
    $xmluser.AppendChild($xmlproperty)
  }
}

# output text
$xml|Format-Xml

# or save to file
$xml.Save('c:\path\to\file.xml')
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Body>
  <User>
    <Username>mike</Username>
    <Password>iamcool</Password>
    <Email>mike@mike.com</Email>
  </User>
  <User>
    <Username>john</Username>
    <Password>hunter2</Password>
    <Email>john@john.com</Email>
  </User>
</Body>
```

Both methods handle encoding special characters for you.